# Using tap gesture's locationInView & CGPoint

Tags: iphone, objective-c

New to iPhone dev. Can someone tell me why

```
-(IBAction) handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    CGPoint *tapPoint = [sender locationInView:imageView];
    NSLog(@"tapped");
}
```

gives me error (for the CGPoint line):

> incompatible types in initialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the * after CGPoint.

Comment: haha.. could've sworn I'd tried that.. guess that's how it goes for newbies

Comment: CGPoint is a structure, not an object/class. Therefore, you do not need to use the *.